# Change number of imported columns in 'importdata' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import

I'm trying to read a very big .seq file. It has thousands of rows and variable number of columns (from 1 to 20), separated with 'space'.
I usually used **importdata** command. However, this time, this command imports this data into matrix with only 2 columns. Is there a way to make importdata command use bigger number of columns?
I also tried to use **dlmread**, but MATLAB says:
Out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). You can use blocks together with xlsread. Read a few thousand at a time.

It can be done by the range input argument in xlsread. In the range itself, you can specify the columns as well..

Syntax:

```
num = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange)
```

Example:

```
filename = 'myExample.xlsx';
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'B2:C3';

subsetA = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange)
```

Read this as well: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html#zmw57dd0e3117

Comment: thanks. but isn't xlsread only for excel documents. MATLAB showed an error File not in Microsoft Excel Format.

Comment: have a look at textscan.. Example: C = textscan(fileID,formatSpec) and read the large text files link i passed you..

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [readtable](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html):

`filename = 'x64.res';
F = readtable(filename,'FileType','text','Delimiter','\t');`